# Why did my SEO question get locked?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm here to make a case that my question [What is missing in my SEO checklist for new websites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84701/what-is-missing-in-my-seo-checklist-for-new-websites) is **not** a duplicate of [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google).

While the latter is a generic catch-all question regarding general SEO-strategies, my question has a very spefific (and much smaller) scope. Also, among the answers, there is no answer that applies to the questions I asked. If my question is a duplicate of this generic question, then by that definition *every* question tagges [seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) on this site would be a duplicate of that one question, as it is basically 'tell me everything I need to know about SEO'.

I edited my question to reflect upon that difference, I hope that you find my request reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not a good fit for this website for several reasons. Being a duplicate was just one of them so I'll start there.

Just looking for *coding* SEO factors is covered in that canonical question. If you don't want to know non-coding SEO factors just *ignore them*. There's no need to have a separate question just because one detail is different especially when that details does not mean additional information not already in the other question would be provided.

Another reason this question is off-topic here is it is too broad. Questions that are looking to compile a list are generally not considered acceptable here  (they were more acceptable for popular topics like the canonical question back when this site was newer). You also have seven bullet points that ask *fifteen questions* in your "question" and, even if asked individually, many are either duplicates of other questions asked here or too broad in-and-of themselves. Calling this question "too broad" actually is an understatement.

Additionally, you ask for recommendations for tutorials which is also off-topic. Questions asking for recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

In a nutshell, this question has too many flaws to being on-topic for this website. Due to its many flaws I do not foresee how you could salvage it to become so.